# No thumbnails preview

Tags: thumbnails

I have installed ubuntu 18.10 and have no thumbnails preview for any file, such as it was in previous version. In preferences the setting is on "show preview" for all files...Any ideas someone?

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug in Ubuntu 18.10 concerning PDF thumbnails.
If the thumbnails preview works with pictures and movies, but not with PDF, you should look [at this LaunchPad bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1798091).

Moreover, you may need to erase the files of this folder:

```
.cache/thumbnails/fail
```